# Spring boot upgrade from 2.1.3.RELEASE to 2.5.12: "No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available" in JUnit run

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2, jdbctemplate

I am getting the below exception when I tried to "mvn package" after upgrading the Spring boot version from 2.1.3.RELEASE to 2.5.12 in JUnit Run

- Upgraded relevant dependency version as well:
  <spring.cloud.version>2.2.6.RELEASE</spring.cloud.version>
- removed junit-jupiter-api and log4j2
- added spring-boot-starter-validation

Below is full stacktrace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:355)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$7(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:350)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:349)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:270)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:269)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:259)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:258)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:100)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:111)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:111)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:79)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'h2Console' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/h2/H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean]: Factory method 'h2Console' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected single matching bean but found 3: snowflakeDataSource,snowflakeAskDataSource,transactionDataSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:448)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:136)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean]: Factory method 'h2Console' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type ' ' available: expected single matching bean but found 3: snowflakeDataSource,snowflakeAskDataSource,transactionDataSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    ... 87 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected single matching bean but found 3: snowflakeDataSource,snowflakeAskDataSource,transactionDataSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveNotUnique(DependencyDescriptor.java:220)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1367)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.getIfAvailable(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:2030)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.ifAvailable(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:2041)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.h2Console(H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.java:66)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 88 more
```

**TransactionalDataConfiguration:**

```
@Configuration
@Log4j2
public class TransactionDataConfiguration {

  private static final String POSTGRES_DATASOURCE_PREFIX = "postgres.datasource";

  /**
   * Configure Snowflake data source and tags it as primary database
   *
   * @return DBCP enabled data source
   */
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = POSTGRES_DATASOURCE_PREFIX)
  @Bean
  @Qualifier("transactionDataSource")
  public DataSource transactionDataSource() {
    log.debug("Creating transaction datasource");
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
  }

  @Bean
  @Qualifier("transactionNamedJdbcTemplate")
  public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate transactionNamedJdbcTemplate(
      @Qualifier("transactionDataSource") DataSource productDataSource) {
    return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(productDataSource);
  }
}
```

**Snowflake Configuration:**

```
@Configuration
@Log4j2
public class SnowflakeConfiguration {

  @Value("${snowflake.datasource.usepassword:false}")
  private boolean usePassword;

  /** Configure Snowflake data source and tags it as primary database */
  @Bean(name = "snowflakeDataSource")
  public DataSource dataSource(Environment env) throws Exception {
    var ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    var connProp = loadSnowflakeConnectionCommonProperties(env);
    connProp.put("warehouse", env.getProperty("snowflake.datasource.reportswarehouse"));
    ds.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("snowflake.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    ds.setUrl(env.getProperty("snowflake.datasource.url"));
    ds.setConnectionProperties(connProp);
    return ds;
  }

  @Bean(name = "snowflakeAskDataSource")
  public DataSource askDataSource(Environment env) throws Exception {
    var ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    var connProp = loadSnowflakeConnectionCommonProperties(env);
    connProp.put("warehouse", env.getProperty("snowflake.datasource.askwarehouse"));
    ds.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("snowflake.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    ds.setUrl(env.getProperty("snowflake.datasource.url"));
    ds.setConnectionProperties(connProp);
    return ds;
  }

  /** Loads connection properties from application.properties file. */
  private Properties loadSnowflakeConnectionCommonProperties(Environment env) throws Exception {
    var prop = new Properties();
    prop.put("user", env.getProperty("snowflake.datasource.username"));
    prop.put("db", env.getProperty("snowflake.datasource.db"));
    prop.put("schema", env.getProperty("snowflake.datasource.schema"));
    prop.put("tracing", env.getProperty("snowflake.datasource.tracing"));
    prop.put("role", env.getProperty("snowflake.datasource.role"));

    if (usePassword) prop.put("password", env.getProperty("snowflake.datasource.password"));
    else
      prop.put(
          "privateKey",
          CommonUtils.generatePrivateKey(
              env.getProperty("snowflake.datasource.privateKey"),
              env.getProperty("snowflake.datasource.passcode")));
    return prop;
  }

  @Bean("masterJdbcTemplate")
  public JdbcTemplate masterJdbcTemplate(
      @Qualifier("snowflakeDataSource") DataSource masterDataSource) {
    var jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(masterDataSource);
    log.debug(" ---------- Creating master jdbcTemplate -------- ");
    return jdbcTemplate;
  }

  @Bean("masterAskJdbcTemplate")
  public JdbcTemplate masterAskJdbcTemplate(
      @Qualifier("snowflakeAskDataSource") DataSource masterDataSource) {
    var jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(masterDataSource);
    log.debug(" ---------- Creating ask jdbcTemplate -------- ");
    return jdbcTemplate;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your application.yml file.  You make sure add this attrubute: spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver

Comment: Problem is that you have 3 different datasource and Spring doesn't know which one to choose from. Spring has been more strict on those checks in later version than it was earlier. You need to remove the unnecessary ones so that there is only one or add a `@Qualifier` to explicitly tell spring which one to use. You have 3 now: `snowflakeDataSource, snowflakeAskDataSource, transactionDataSource`

Comment: can you add snowflakeDataSource,snowflakeAskDataSource,transactionDataSource bean configs code?

Comment: @ArunSai Added bean configs code.

Comment: @Saurabh Gadariya Can you add H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration.java class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally able to run test-cases by switching off h2 console

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have no unique bean, you have actually 3 beans that could be injected there, those beans are:

```
snowflakeDataSource,snowflakeAskDataSource,transactionDataSource
```

and your h2Console cannot choose the datasource. As I understand.

You could add names to your beans:

```
@Component("myBean")
```

And then you can use this with Qualifier annotation later.

Or exclude them, but I think none of those datasources are good probably...

Would be good to check your property file, you shall have something similar to this there:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:mydb
    username: sa
    password: password
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things I noticed:

#### 1) Above some datasources you have a comment saying `tags it as primary database`

This is a fine thing to do, but you don't actually tag those as primary. For that you need to use the `@Primary` annotation.

#### 2) You can't have multiple Primary datasources

There can be only one primary datasource, so tagging multiple of them as primary is wrong and will result in an error. You need to choose one datasource to tag as primary and coincidentally, that datasource is the one you'll be able to interact with from your H2 Console.